# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS crashes while browsing and while training with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-shell

I'm getting strange behavior in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS since the very begining I freshly installed it along with Windows in a dual boot config. While I'm using it, even if I'm browsing, coding or training Neural Networks with Tensorflow I'm getting random OS crashes, screen freezes and gnome errors. I got this info from /var/log/syslog right after gnome crashed and started again.

```
    May 14 20:44:09 APC-L gnome-shell[10844]: Some code accessed the property 'WindowPreviewMenu' on the module 'windowPreview'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
May 14 20:45:08 APC-L gnome-session-binary[2276]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
May 14 20:45:08 APC-L gnome-session[2276]: gnome-session-binary[2276]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): GBT AORUS AD27QD (DFP-5): connected
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): GBT AORUS AD27QD (DFP-5): Internal DisplayPort
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): GBT AORUS AD27QD (DFP-5): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: disconnected
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: Internal DisplayPort
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2262]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L gsd-media-keys[2588]: g_variant_get_va: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L gsd-media-keys[2588]: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L org.gnome.Shell.desktop[12786]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L dbus-daemon[1011]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.155' (uid=1000 pid=12786 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L dbus-daemon[1011]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
May 14 20:45:17 APC-L gnome-shell[12786]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
May 14 20:45:18 APC-L gnome-shell[12786]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
May 14 20:45:18 APC-L gnome-shell[12786]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.96/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
May 14 20:45:18 APC-L gnome-shell[12786]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.96/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/livepatch
May 14 20:45:18 APC-L gnome-shell[12786]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
May 14 20:45:27 APC-L gnome-shell[12786]: GNOME Shell started at Thu May 14 2020 20:45:17 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

I think it might be a NVIDIA driver issue... I have installed the latest propietary driver from NVIDIA 440.82 in several ways (nvidia web page run file, ubuntu software&update or ppa package). My hardware is listed below:

- MB: MSI Z370 PC PRO
- RTX 2080
- i9 9900K
- Samsung 970 EVO 1TB
- EVGA G2 SUPERNOVA 750W

My tensorflow version, in case that matters, is Tensorflow:  2.3.0-dev20200514.

Currently I'm testing with a docker container created out of the image tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu.

Thanks in advance.